# How to Hide window Taskbar while taking Screen Shot using JAVA

Tags: java, image, hide, screenshot, snapshot

I am using below code for screen shot but i want to hide window taskbar only.
Is there any specific code for that without enter the dimension. 
I don't want enter dimension because every PC has different.. 
Please Suggest. Thanks in advance.

Robot robot = new Robot();
  Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            Rectangle captureRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(captureRect);

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do some pixel manipulations. Take a screenshot, start looking from bottom for the first row in which every pixel in it is different from the pixel in the same column but in the upper row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but i dont want to enter pixel manually because every device have different pixel of monitor...is there any specific keyword for hide taskbar

Comment: It doesn't mean to give sizze manually. I'l' explain. The screenshot gives the exact screen size of the computer including taskbar. The method i mentioned simply gives the height of the taskbar. Subtracting this height from the screen height will give you exactly the screen size of that computer excluding taskbar.